# Reading the metadata of an external site before hyperlinking

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, metadata

Bit of a theoretical one here as I'm currently searching for a way to ensure that websites I have worked on always show the version that I created or if they are not available, revert to a localized version.

So, for example, I developed a few sites back in 2009 that have since been re-designed or re-implemented by the client meaning that the work I link to on my portfolio page is no longer the original I developed. I have therefore been searching as to whether it is possible to create a hyperlink on my portfolio that when clicked runs a script that goes away and checks the content of an external page to see if the content

```
    <meta name="author" content="JME" />
```

for example. However, if this is not present in the meta data then the link should instead revert to a localized version of the initial template I developed to ensure my work is still showcased.

Is there a way of querying the external metadata using PHP so that this type of workaround can be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible: open the external site, do a [`get_meta_tags()`](http://php.net/get-meta-tags), look for the existence of the tag. It's not a good idea to do this every time the page is called, though - it would be so slow it would very likely annoy your visitors.

A frequent check (say, once a week) using a cron job would be the best way to go.

Comment: I don't think I'll be going down the whole cron route as I have no idea what that is. I will however use the get_meta_tags function to check the author array value to see if it is equal to JME and if not, hyperlink to a local page instead. I know it's probably not the best speed-wise but as there will be images of the site on the portfolio page I doubt a user will be clicking through to the live site anyway. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @jezzi no problem. Images won't be loaded if you use `get_meta_tags()` so it won't be *that* slow, but the delay may still be noticeable if you have plenty of sites. You could ask your web host / admin whether they offer cron jobs, they will know what they are and should be able to tell you how to set one up if they have them.

Comment: I'm currently between hosts as I'm re-developing an old portfolio site I had but I'll definitely consider this when looking for a host. Thanks buddy!